# What this the best way to validate a form without using "Fancy Javascript"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, validation

I am using [`backbone.syphone`](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon)  to serialize data and save them to the server.

I am wondering what is the best way to handle the error or validate the date before to send them to the server without using "Fancy Javascript".

P.S.

I just need to check all the fields are not empty.

here is my code:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    submitData: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = backboneSyphon.serialize(this);
        myModel.save(data, {
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fancy javascript"?

Comment: define "fancy javascript". Are you trying to avoid using a library, like jQuery or MooTools?

Comment: OP is using Backbone, which requires JQuery (or at least Zepto, which is like a scaled-down jQuery).

Comment: Actually, I take that back; just re-checked the Backbone site and you *can* run Backbone without jQuery (it's just that all the View/DOM manipulation bits won't work without it).  While I'd imagine that's pretty rare, I guess it's possible OP is not using jQuery or Zepto.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to do purely server-side validation you will *have* to use *some* Javascript to do the validation; I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "fancy".  Since you're using Backbone, that very likely means you're using jQuery (well, or Zepto), so I'll consider jQuery to be within "fanciness" boundaries ;-)

With jQuery, the simplest JS I can think of would be something like:

```
var failed;
$('#yourForm :input').each(function(input) {
    if (!$(input).val()) {
        alert("You need to fill in " + input.name);
        failed = true;
        return false;
    }
}
// Do whatever else you want to do if (failed)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use fancy javascript code,
in your case, since you are using Backbone,
I recommend you to use backbone.validation.

Here's the link to this library: [backbone.validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation/blob/master/backbone.validation.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "non fancy javascript" :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title></title>
<form id="form" method="post" action="someform.php">
<input id="name" name="Name" value="Name*">
<input type="submit" value="">
</form>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
var yourForm = document.getElementById('form'),
    yourInput = document.getElementById('name');

yourForm.onsubmit = function () {
    if(yourInput.value == yourInput.defaultValue || yourInput.value == '') {
        alert('You must write something');
        return false;
    }
}
}
</script>
```